The fundamental solution of the diffusion equation with a non-constant diffusion coefficient.
We know that the fundamental solution of the diffusion equation
$$\partial_t u -\partial_{xx}u=0$$
is given by
$$
K(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}.
$$
Clearly, $K(t,x) > 0 $. However, consider the equation with a non-constant diffusion coefficient:
$$\partial_t u - \partial_x(a(x)u_x) = 0,$$
where $ a(x) \in C^{\infty}$ and $a(x) \geqslant a_0 > 0$ for some constant $ a_0 $. Is the fundamental solution of this equation also positive everywhere? Intuitively, from a physical perspective, it seems trivial since the mass of matter cannot be negative in diffusion process. However, how can we rigorously prove this?

In your non-constant diffusion coefficient do you really mean $\partial_x$, or should it be $\partial_{xx}$?

Sorry, I made a typo.
